# Compile aspx page "on the fly"

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to build an aspx page at runtime (by another aspx page which finally redirects to the new one). As far as I understand, aspx pages MUST be precompiled before a user can view them. In other words, the aspx page must be compiled to the DLL in the /bin folder.

Is there a away to tell IIS, or to order it by VB.NET code, to compile a page before I am redirecting my user to the page?

Any help would be greatly appriciated.

Comment: Usually this idea sound like a wrong (or at least a questionable) design desicion. I never was in the need for bulding ASPX pages on the fly. What would your usage scenario look like for such a feature?

Comment: If you can write code to create some output into a new ASPX page, you could as well instruct your code to output it on the _current_ ASPX page.

Comment: Uwe Keim, Thank you for your quick reply. I am trying to build a custom page according to database information. That is, my database holds the page structure XML, and then I am building my aspx page according to it. Only after I have built my aspx page, I need to compile it for the user to be able to navigate to it.

Comment: I would output the structure within the current page, not in a new page. E.g. having a nearly blank page and simply outputting the content of the database dynamically on that page.

Comment: No, you don't... Aspx itself doesn't have to be compiled, only its code-behind, if such exists. However, this is a bad idea altogether. Simply create a single page that parses your db data and use url rewriting/routing...

Comment: OK. How ever, I don`t think you can output an aspx tags dyanmically. I must have aspx tages and not just HTML tags. If you know how to dynamically output aspx tags (such as aspx:button or any other one) dynamically, can you show me how please ?

Comment: Just to second @walther, I do think this is a huge mess, to have ASPX code inside a database.

Comment: So, can you show me how to dynamically return aspx tags ? I have tryed to use <% Response.Write("aspxtagstring") %> and it does not work....

Comment: Why would you return aspx tags??? Browser can't parse aspx tags, it needs html.

Comment: Thats OK so far, but in order to use third party controls (such as Telerik) I would need aspx tags. But... I will now try to return simple HTML tags and see if it works... two seconds buddy !

Comment: Well... HTML tags works. How ever, in order to use thrid party components, I need to have aspx tags. Any idea maybe ? And by the way, many thanks for your help!

Comment: I think you're going on the wrong path; never heard of putting aspx code inside a database to create an aspx on the fly. You should rethink your design. If you need to handle logic branches based on certain criteria then you use "if" statements inside your code-behind and handle contingencies there.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [VirtualPathProvider class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.hosting.virtualpathprovider.aspx) to load pages from a database.

Comment: Hi, Stephen. Try to add links to documentation when pointing to some class/method/function/language so that people can dive into the subject easier. Also, it helps to avoid ambiguity when some name is very common.

Comment: Sorry here are a couple of links. The second is an example which fetches pages form a database.[link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/910441) also [link](http://www.bipinjoshi.net/articles/fbc64253-aa68-4087-8ac5-bd56a2902979.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Basicallly what you need is to render content of the page dynamically. You can create page content dynamically on server side by adding controls (HTML or Server Ones) to controls collection for example to place holder server element.

For example you can create page with the following markup:

```
    <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="TestPage.aspx.cs" Inherits="StackOverflowWebApp.TestPage" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePartialRendering="true" />

    <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="ContentPlaceHolder"></asp:PlaceHolder>

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

And then in code behind class we can add controls to render which is necessary dynamically be reading information from database.

```
    using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace StackOverflowWebApp
{
    public partial class TestPage : Page
    {
        #region Methods

        protected override void CreateChildControls()
        {
            base.CreateChildControls();

            // HERE get configuration from database.

            // HERE create content of the page dynamically.

            // Add reference to css file.
            HtmlLink link = new HtmlLink { Href = "~/Styles/styles.css" };
            link.Attributes.Add("type", "text/css");
            link.Attributes.Add("rel", "stylesheet");
            this.Page.Header.Controls.Add(link);

            // Add inline styles.
            HtmlGenericControl inlineStyle = new HtmlGenericControl("style");
            inlineStyle.InnerText = "hr {color:sienna;} p {margin-left:20px;}";
            this.Page.Header.Controls.Add(inlineStyle);

            // Add div with css class and styles.
            HtmlGenericControl div = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
            this.ContentPlaceHolder.Controls.Add(div);
            div.Attributes.Add("class", "SomeCssClassName");
            div.Attributes.CssStyle.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.ZIndex, "1000");

            TextBox textBox = new TextBox { ID = "TestTextBox" };
            div.Controls.Add(textBox);

            // and etc
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Note: this example can be a start point to create dynamic pages which content depend on values specified in database or configuration.

Comment: Maxim, Thank you so much for your reply. How ever, doing it like this, make it almost unpossible (and correct me if Im wroing) to add certain CSS style string to the created object. Am I right ?

Comment: I updated example. You can add reference to css, add styles to controls and so on. You also can render stylesheet dynamically to page. You can do almost as you want. Even more you can render the html markup you want even without adding controls to control collection. See at the render method of the page (or you can create custom control which will render HTML makrup you want).

Comment: Maxim, you may solved my problem. Just one more question remains. In your example you showed how to use an external CSS file. What can I do if I want to add custom css PER OBJECT ?

Comment: You can add inline css styles to page header element. I updated examples.

Comment: Umm... nope. I am getting an error saying that my control must be within a form and runat=server. I DO have a form tag and the runat=server...

Comment: Check you code and markup. The provided example works well (i verified it using test web application). You need to identify difference in your markup/code yourself.